# Is there a way to get DLC for a PSP UMD using the PS3

Tags: psn, psp

i found out that the encryption on my router is not supported on PSPs in general (the security is WPA however the encryption itself is not supported), while looking on the next, mostly every answer i see about people trying to get there PSP's to access a router is to either change the encryption (which i can't do), change the security to WEP which is easier hacked or turn off the security

I know with the PS3 you can download PSP Games and copy them to the PSP apart from 1 game i'm getting, all my PSP Games are in UMD Format, so i'm wondering if there is a way to use the PS3 to download DLC for my PSP

Comment: If you can buy it from the PSN store using the PS3, you should be able to transfer it to your PSP. If not, try using Media Go.

Comment: He means that he can buy it, but it won't download over his connection through to his PSP, just his PS3. I think you can do the same thing with DLC though, just buy it for te PS3 hook it up to the PS3 with a USB cable and copy it through. I don't know what else to tell you, I'm not even quite sure thats what you're asking, its an oddly worded question :/

Answer (score 3):

Download the DLC from the PSN store on the PS3 and then install it to your PSP from the PS3 just like you would full games (eg, USB connect PSP to PS3 and pick install on the download icon from the PS3).